# MySQL can't connect as user with password locally

Tags: mysql-5.5, security

I am running into a strange authentification issue.

Users can't connect to MySQL locally using a password, but they can without one.

```
mysql -h localhost -u someuser -psomepassword
```

won't work

but

```
mysql -u someuser -h localhost
```

does

Those same users can connect remotely to this machine using their passwords.

```
mysql -u someuser -h someserver -psomepassword
```

Any thoughts as to why passwords can't be used locally?

Notes :

1. MySQL's logs are not providing anything useful
2. Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-45-generic x86_64)
3. mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35
4. root can connect with password remotely or locally

**Update 08/10 9:39**

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| user()          | current_user() |
+-----------------+----------------+
| Guest@localhost | @localhost     |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: When you connect, please run `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`. What's the output ???

Comment: HI @RolandoMySQLDBA, I updated my answer.